# Bracket issue in snakemake cluster command

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, snakemake

I am using snakemake 4.0.0 on aws cfncluster with the following commands.

```
rule fastq_to_counts:
input: fastql="/shared/dbGAP/sras2/fastq.gz/{sample}_1.fastq.gz", fastqr="/shared/dbGAP/sras2/fastq.gz/{sample}_2.fastq.gz"
output: "/shared/counts/{sample}"
shell: '/shared/packages/sailfish-master/bin/sailfish quant -i /shared/packages/gencode26/gencode26 -l IU -p 1  -1 <(zcat {input.fastql})  -2 <(zcat {input.fastqr})       --output  {output}'
```

It runs fine on the head node but when I submit to head node i get the following error.

```
    /shared/packages/sailfish-master/bin/sailfish quant -i /shared/packages/gencode26/gencode26 -l IU -p 1  -1 <(zcat /shared/dbGAP/sras2/fastq.gz/xxx.fastq.gz)  -2 <(zcat /shared/dbGAP/sras2/fastq.gz/xxx.fastq.gz)       --output  /shared/counts/SRR1075530 
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Error in job fastq_to_counts while creating output file /shared/counts/xxx.
```

RuleException:

The issue is that the "sh" command does not support "bashism" of the "(" 
is there any way to force snakemake to use /bin/bash ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found that the solution is adding the following to snakefile
shell.executable('bash')